# NSTimer Pause not working

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nstimer

I have setup three buttons with `start`,`stop`,`pause`. and given controls to NSTimer to calculates.start stop button works fine gives me the start and stop time but `pause`button does not gives me accurate time .it actually pause time ..but start again it adds the paused timed and disp[ay.
supoose i pause at 5 second of start and wait for 5 sec then press start...it should display 5 ...but displaying 10..

```
-(void)start:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  if(_timer==nil)
  {
    startDate =[NSDate date];

    _timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(timer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  }

  if(_timer!=nil)
  { 
    float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];

    [_timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
  }

}

-(void)timer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  NSInteger secondsSinceStart = (NSInteger)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];

  NSInteger seconds = secondsSinceStart % 60;
  NSInteger minutes = (secondsSinceStart / 60) % 60;
  NSInteger hours = secondsSinceStart / (60 * 60);
  NSString *result = nil;
  if (hours > 0) 
  {
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
  }
  else 
  {
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];        
  }

  label.text=result;

  NSLog(@"time interval -> %@",result);
}

-(void)stop
{
  if(_timer!=nil)
  {
    endDate = [NSDate date];
 NSLog(@"endate%@",endDate);

     NSTimeInterval interval = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSLog(@"total time %f",interval);
    [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = nil; 
  startDate=nil;
  }
}

-(void)pause:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  pauseStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];

  previousFireDate = [_timer fireDate];

  [_timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm right, but may be you should invalidate the timer before doing a "setFireDate" ?

Comment: When you pause the timer. store the sec. And only increment once it is started.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya bro I am trying the same

Comment: @AnoopVaidya what I did ,by putting `NSTimeInterval interval = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate: pauseStart];
NSLog(@"total time %f",interval);` in (void) pause I calculated the paused time...now how do I increment to the current time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created  this [applicaion](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5387039/timerstopwatch-3-zip-43k?da=y) on  mac os. I think you can understand the logic and even copy this with minor changes...as for UILabel.

In .h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

- (IBAction)start:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *label;

@property (strong)NSDate *startDate;
@property (strong)NSTimer *timer;

@property (assign)BOOL isRunning;
@property (assign)BOOL isPaused;

@property(assign)NSInteger secondsSinceStart;

@property(assign)NSInteger secondsPaused;
@end
```

In .m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.label.stringValue=@"00:00:00";
    self.isRunning=NO;
    self.isPaused=NO;
    self.secondsPaused=0;
}

-(void)timerDisplay{

    if (self.isPaused) {
        self.secondsPaused++;
        return;
    }

    self.secondsSinceStart+=1;

    NSInteger seconds = self.secondsSinceStart % 60;
    NSInteger minutes = (self.secondsSinceStart / 60) % 60;
    NSInteger hours = self.secondsSinceStart / (60 * 60);
    NSString *result = nil;


    if (self.isRunning && !self.isPaused) {
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", hours, minutes, seconds];
        self.label.stringValue=result;
    }
}


- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {
    self.isRunning=!self.isRunning;
    self.isPaused=NO;
    self.secondsSinceStart=0;
    self.label.stringValue=@"00:00:00";


    self.startDate =[NSDate date];
    if (!self.timer) {
        self.timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender {
    self.isPaused=!self.isPaused;
    NSLog(@"pause : %d",self.isPaused);
}

- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender {
    self.isRunning=NO;
    NSLog(@"start : %@",self.startDate);
    NSLog(@"end : %@",[NSDate date]);
    NSLog(@"paused : %ld",self.secondsPaused);

    NSInteger totalTime=self.secondsSinceStart+self.secondsPaused;

    NSInteger seconds = totalTime % 60;
    NSInteger minutes = (totalTime / 60) % 60;
    NSInteger hours = totalTime / (60 * 60);
    NSString *result = result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", hours, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@"Total : %@",result);

}
@end
```

Comment: any doubt or comment is appreciable :)

Comment: ya sorry bro,I check this late...This works fine but only thing this left to calculate time from start to stop ... I am doing..this in stop function.`Stop = [NSDate date];
    
    NSTimeInterval interval = [Stop timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];`...but this does not give me the exact time..

Comment: create another NSDate and endDate. And as you press Stop... store the endDate=[nsdate date], and then calculate the differnce between startDate & endDate. And remember this will count the paused time. If you want to discard the paused time, then subtract the seconds from there...

Comment: thats wat i did..but how to subtract the pause time..how to store this ..I am unable to store

Comment: dont worry dude... will update the answer with this feature tomorw...  fir bhi try karta hu teamviewr se office mac ko access karne ka.

Answer (score 1):

It will never ever work for you because NSTimer cant be pause, it will Start and It will only Stop when you will invalidate it. when it will in valid state it means it is running and when the state is not valid it means Timer is stopped. Thanks

Comment: then how can i give Pause button

Comment: you have write you own custom class for this, that class with handle these two method, like resume, pause.